# How do I replicate the admin dashboard in meanjs to create a user directory

Tags: meanjs

I am new to meanjs but I am currently trying to create a simple app where users can connect to each other.

Right now I just want to implement a function where users can look each other up by search and nothing else but I keep running into a 403 error. I tried to fix it by replicating the documents that make up the admin 'manage users' view.

I didn't want to give everyone the 'admin' role so I added a new policy for users where they are given only 'get' permissions. I also added a new route, view and controller for regular user that is modified from the admin files.

It has worked pretty well but I still can't get the system to allow access to the new userDirectory view when logged in under a non-admin role. I think it has something to do with the auth.interceptor.client.service.js file and the modules/core/client/app/init.js file and the $state being provided by the new files I made but I have tried to modify them and it still is throwing up the /forbidden view in the body of my app.

I am at a loss for what else I can do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The app starts with home.client.view.html view:

```html
<section ng-controller="HomeController">

  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center" ng-hide="authentication.user">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <img alt="MEAN.JS" class="img-responsive text-center" src="modules/core/client/img/brand/Logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <p class="lead">
        An app
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>
        <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="http://meanjs.org" target="_blank">Learn more</a> -->
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="authentication.user">
    <h2>Congratulations! You are logged in.</h2>
    <div ng-include="'/modules/users/client/views/user/user-directory.client.view.html'"></div>
    <!-- <div ng-include="'/api/users'"></div> -->

  </div>

</section>
```

Here is my view for the userDirectory (modified from modules/users/client/views/admin/list-users.client.view.html):

```html
<section ng-controller="UserDirectoryController">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1>Users</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 2em">
        <input class="form-control col-md-4" type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search" ng-change="figureOutItemsToDisplay()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group">
    <a ng-repeat="user in pagedSearchItems" ui-sref="users.user({userId: user._id})" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" ng-bind="user.username"></h4>
      <p class="list-group-item-text" ng-bind="user.email"></p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <pagination boundary-links="true" max-size="8" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" total-items="filterLength" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
</section>
```

My Controller (modified from modules/users/client/controllers/admin/list-users.client.controller.js):

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('users.user').controller('UserDirectoryController', ['$scope', '$filter', 'User',
  function ($scope, $filter, User) {
    User.query(function (data) {
      $scope.users = data;
      $scope.buildPager();
    });

    $scope.buildPager = function () {
      $scope.pagedSearchItems = [];
      $scope.itemsPerPage = 15;
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
      $scope.figureOutItemsToDisplay();
    };

    $scope.figureOutItemsToDisplay = function () {
      $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.users, {
        $: $scope.search
      });
      $scope.filterLength = $scope.filteredItems.length;
      var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage);
      var end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
      $scope.pagedSearchItems = $scope.filteredItems.slice(begin, end);
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
      $scope.figureOutItemsToDisplay();
    };
  }
]);
```

My Service (modified from modules/users/client/services/users.client.service.js):

```js
'use strict';

// Users service used for communicating with the users REST endpoint
angular.module('users').factory('User', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/userDirectory', {}, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);

//TODO this should be Users service
angular.module('users.user').factory('User', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/userDirectory/:userId', {
      userId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);

angular.module('users.user').factory('User', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/userDirectory/:userId', {
      userId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

My new route.js (modified from modules/users/server/routes/admin.server.routes.js):

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var userPolicy = require('../policies/userDirectory.server.policy'),
  userDirectory = require('../controllers/userDirectory.server.controller');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // User route registration first. Ref: #713
  require('./users.server.routes.js')(app);

  // Users collection routes
  app.route('/api/userDirectory')
    .get(userPolicy.isAllowed, userDirectory.list);

  //Single user routes
  app.route('/api/userDirectory/:userId')
    .get(userPolicy.isAllowed, userDirectory.read);

  // Finish by binding the user middleware
  app.param('userId', userDirectory.userByID);
};
```

And finally my new policy for userDirectory (modified from modules/users/server/policies/admin.server.policy.js):

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var acl = require('acl');

// Using the memory backend
acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());

/**
 * Invoke User Permissions
 */
exports.invokeRolesPolicies = function () {
  acl.allow([{
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/userDirectory',
      permissions: ['post', 'get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/userDirectory/:userId',
      permissions: ['post', 'get']
    }]
  }]);
};

/**
 * Check If User Policy Allows
 */
exports.isAllowed = function (req, res, next) {
  var roles = (req.user) ? req.user.roles : ['guest'];

// Check for user roles
  acl.areAnyRolesAllowed(roles, req.route.path, req.method.toLowerCase(), function (err, isAllowed) {
    if (err) {
      // An authorization error occurred.
      return res.status(500).send('Unexpected authorization error');
    } else {
      if (isAllowed) {
        // Access granted! Invoke next middleware
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({
          message: 'User is not authorized'
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is to add a new route to the server which only users can access and create a service to retrieve that data.

(This is only a service for getting the data from the DB, you can use it in any view/controller, or create a new view which is only accessible to the users/admins)

In your module (client side) create a service to perform a http post/get to the server:

```
(function() {
 'use strict';
 angular
   .module('yourModule')
   .factory('UserListService', function($http) {
     var routes = {};
     routes.getUserList = function(username) {
       return $http.post('/api/userlist', username); //you can do a 'post' to search for one username or just 'get' to see all users.
     };
     return routes;
   }
 );
})();
```

and then in `modulses/yourModule/server/routes` add the route:

```
app.route('/api/userlist').all(yourModulePolicy.isAllowed)
.post(yourModule.getUserList); //get or post its up to you
```

don't forget to add permissions in `modulses/yourModule/server/policies`

```
roles: ['user'],
allows: [{
  resources: '/api/userlist',
  permissions: ['post'] //get or post
}]
```

then handle the request in `modulses/yourModule/server/controllers`

```
exports.getUserList = function(req, res) {
  var name_to_search = req.body.username;
  //here you can query the database for all users or the name you
  //received in the post.
  //NOTE: if you query the user DB there can be sensitive information
  //such as the hashed password etc, make sure you delete that here
  //before you respond with the user/user list
  res.jsonp(user_list);
};
```

after this you can use the user information in the client side controller like this:

```
UserListService.getUserList({
   username: 'john'
 }).then(function(data) {
   vm.userlist = data.data;
 });
```

Make sure to inject UserListService into the controller and pass it to the controller function:

`YourController.$inject = ['UserListService'];`

and

`function YourController(UserListService){...}`

Hope this helps, i'm also new to the whole mean stack, don't even know if this is the best solution, but it will work.

EDIT:

When you create a new view on the client side with a controller you need to add it to the client side routes in `modules/yourModule/client/config/yourModule.client.routes.js`

```
.state('your.state', {
        url: '-yourUrl',
        templateUrl: 'modules/yourModule/client/views/user-list.client.view.html',
        controller: 'YourController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
          roles: ['user', 'admin'],
          pageTitle: 'User List'
        }
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Luke. I just edited my question and added my code. I feel like I covered everything you referred to but my user-directory view keeps going back to the wrong route. It keeps going back to the 'api/users' route instead of my new route 'api/userDirectory'. I think it has to do with angularJS code in the view. But I may be wrong. If you have the opportunity could you look over my code and tell me why you think it isn't working or at least where my logic is lacking. Thanks again for your response!

Comment: @AaronPennington I looked at your code, did you add your view and controller to the client side routes  ? In /modules/yourModule/client/config/yourModule.client.routes.js ? I will edit my answer to add the code.

Comment: I think the problem was in the client.routes.js file. I had a typo in the controller name, fixed it and now the app works great. Thanks so much for your help!